# EditText is not displaying translation while Logcat does

Tags: android, translate, yandex, yandex-api

I am using Yandex.Translate API to translate a String. It does so successfully as seen in the logcat. But when I set the EditText value (eText) to the translation result, it doesn't parse the data correctly and it shows something like {"code":200,"lang":"en-ru","text":["Он не работает!"]}, the second result instead of the first required result which is "Он не работает!"

```
2019-06-11 02:36:57.917 14680-                      
14731/com.bahraindiction.goldeneagle.sightling D/Translation Result:: Он 
не работает!
2019-06-11 02:36:57.918 
1468014680/com.bahraindiction.goldeneagle.sightling D/Translation Result:         
{"code":200,"lang":"en-ru","text":["Он не работает!"]}
```

```
       TranslatorBackgroundTask translatorBackgroundTask= new TranslatorBackgroundTask(context);
       String translationResult = null; // Returns the translated text as a String
       try {
           translationResult = translatorBackgroundTask.execute(textToBeTranslated,languagePair).get();
       } catch (ExecutionException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       Log.d("Translation Result",translationResult); // Logs the result in Android Monitor
       eText.setText(translationResult);
   }
```

As seen above, Log.d displays the translated result correctly AND displays the "unparsed" translation, while eText only displays the unparsed result only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

translationResult is in JSON format, Please parse that JSON first and pick the text string and set to eText. You can use gson or similar library to parse JSON.

Comment: I just checked out the class that I was importing to parse the text. I was so dumb not to notice it at first and I was about to remove the question but you answered first. Thank you anyways, and I'll leave the question to any dumb people like me coming up with this problem in the future :)

Comment: It's okay, this small things happen all the time. Glad to hear that, you figured that yourself as well.